# Mixin doesn't see the variable

Tags: css, sass

faced an error: mixin does not see the variable in the external environment where it was included.

Example of inserting a mixin:

```css
button.endBurger {
    $color: rgba(247, 181, 82, $opacity-bg_conf); // variable that mixin does not see
    background-color: $color;
    width: 250px;
    @include hover-active_add-buts;
}
```

The mixin:

```css
@mixin hover-active_add-buts {
    &:hover {
        background: darken($color, $darken-k_add-buts);
    }
    &:active {
        background: darken($color, $darken-k-act_add-buts);
    }
}
```

Error code:

> Error: Undefined variable: "$color"

Comment: you can define your variable in single file and import it main file where you are using.

Comment: @deepak, no I can`t. There are many similar rules and the variable in them always contains different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the scope of `$color` isn't global, you need to pass it as an argument :

```
button.endBurger {
    $color: rgba(247, 181, 82, $opacity-bg_conf); // переменная, которую не видит миксина
    background-color: $color;
    width: 250px;
    @include hover-active_add-buts($color);
}

@mixin hover-active_add-buts($color) {
    &:hover {
        background: darken($color, $darken-k_add-buts);
    }
    &:active {
        background: darken($color, $darken-k-act_add-buts);
    }
}
```